# “Ageing is more and more difficult for many people” or “Ageing is the more and more difficult for many people”

Tags: grammar

Which one is more correct:

> “Ageing is more and more difficult for many people”

or

> “Ageing is **the** more and more difficult for many people”

Comment: ***Aging***...  Also, aging is the easiest thing in the world for every single person out there.  It happens without them even having to think about it.

Comment: Don't use _the_ with the comparative (_more, less, X-er than_). _The_ is only used with the superlative (_the most, the least, the X-est of_). Also, do you really mean to say that humans have more difficulty growing old than they used to?

Comment: @JohnLawler "The more the merrier."

Comment: @Katy: **"The *(comparative)*, the *(comparative)*"** is a special construct, which is not used in this context.

Comment: @virolino, Yes, but my comment was to indicate that *the* is not "only" used with superlatives. The more accurate we can be, the better.

Comment: I'm sorry I downvoted. Even though I am a non native speaker, the misspelling like aging is fatal if the OP wants the answer.

Comment: @Katy: you are correct when you say "the is not "only" used with superlatives". It can be used with nouns and it can be used in certain expressions / constructs. BUT, it cannot be used with (simple) comparatives. And in this question, we have a comparative; not nouns, not special constructs.

Comment: @KentaroTomono: this is from the Cambridge Dictionary: "present participle UK **ageing** or US **aging**, past tense and past participle **aged**". From: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/age

Comment: @virolino Ah, thank you very much. Though I have to apologize to British, spelling like "ageing" looks very strange. You could pronounce as "ah-ge-ing".

Comment: @KentaroTomono I have seen stranger things than that. In more languages, not only in English. :)

Comment: @Katy Also, *aging is **the** more difficult option* is grammatical. The article is quite normal when used with a comparative as part of adjectival phrase.

Comment: @JasonBassford: just wondering: in your example, "the" actually determines "option", and it sits near "more" just by chance (in the same way that is just after "is"). Even if "more" is removed, "the" is still needed. Right? If yes, then "the" is not in a construct with a comparative, unlike  "the (comparative), the (comparative)"

Comment: @virolino No, *the* is never *required*. You could also use the indefinite article in either case. However, the definite article is more common when the comparative is present, and less common when it's absent.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I had good thinking and bad words. I meant that a non-zero article is required, as you explained (either definite or indefinite). Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is simple. Once you notice that "more and more" is just a "form" of "more", and "more" is the comparative of "much / many", then it becomes obvious that "the" is totally misplaced.

Therefore the following is correct:

> “Ageing is more and more difficult for many people”